# Syntax Error, first line after dostuff

Tags: perl, loops, timer

Here is the code.  I'll be honest, I'm not very versed in Perl and I have copied from this site to build what you see below, more or less.  Another post here, [Run a sub in a perl script based on the time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7210740/run-a-sub-in-a-perl-script-based-on-the-time), shows the basics for the while function(?), but it errors out after the first variable I have.  Tried double quotes, singles quotes, not sure what else to try.  Any thoughts on why this is failing so quickly?
 The rest of the code works without it, but I need this script to be run every 30 minutes.  We may go with Windows to run it (I have a powershell script that works already), but there is a chance we may run it on Unix/Linux and we may just go with Perl anyways for cross-platform use.

Also, I'm testing in Windows currently for ease of use.  I'm more of a Windows guy, but I do have some code that will run on Linux, just easier for me to test this way.

Thanks in advance!

Errors

syntax error at D:\mount\script.pl line 13, near near "15;"

syntax error at D:\mount\script.pl line 36, near ")"

```
while (1)
    {
    dostuff
        (
            my $timeout = 15;
            my $cellname = "PRD-BPPM";

        #Variable for time in epoch because Windows is stupid and can't post it like EVERY OTHER OS out there
            my $endtimew = "1416788994";
            my $starttimew = $endtimew - 1800;
            print "$endtimew\n";
            print "$starttimew\n\n";

        #Windows
            my $mquery_win = "D:\\BMC_Software\\BPPMAgent\\Agent\\server\\bin\\mquery.exe -n \@192.168.0.104/1828#mc -a EVENT -v -l D:\\BMC_Software\\BPPMAgent\\Agent\\server -s \"mc_host,date_reception\" -w \"date_reception: between [$starttimew,$endtimew]\" -f CSV >> E:\\powershell.csv";

        #Windows
            system($mquery_win);

            print $mquery_win;

            open(TIDAL,'E:\\powershell.csv');
            my @array = <TIDAL>;
            close TIDAL;
            open(OUT,'>','E:\\powershell.csv');
            print OUT @array[2..$#array];
            close OUT;
        );
                sleep($timeout);
    };
```

Comment: Note `dostuff();` vs `dostuff( your whole script inserted );` Also turning `use strict; use warnings;` is recommended.

Comment: Eh, I'm an idiot.  It appears that nothing goes IN the parentheses.... :-|  Still working on this, but makes sense...sorta.  I am using strict, not warnings, but I will add that.  Just posted the code of the text I'm working with.  Upating the original to show what I have for everything, top to bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're having some basic confusion about how the Perl syntax works.  Allow me to back up a step.

Here's a while loop that prints a message every thirty seconds:

```
while(1){
    print "hi, mom!\n";
    sleep 30;
}
```

Here's a while loop that calls `dostuff()` every thirty seconds

```
while(1){
    dostuff();
    sleep 30;
}
```

Got that? Now we need to define `dostuff()`, so we add this:

```
sub dostuff {
    print "hi, mom!\n";
}
```

put them together and it'll look like this:

```
# here's your loop that *calls* dostuff()
while(1){
    dostuff();
    sleep 30;
}
# here's where you *define* a subroutine called "dostuff"
sub dostuff {
    print "hi, mom!\n";
    # and obviously all that other code would go in here
}
```

Is that helpful?

Comment: Yes, very.  As I was trying to continue to figure this out, I found that dostuff is always dostuff() in the examples and THEN the light went off.  I'll work on this some more and update to reflect the notes you've provided.  Thank you!

Comment: Timer is working now, thanks again.  Trying to get the file to looping stuff to work right, but I'll get that figured out.  The first file writes and then removes the lines correctly, but the next time I think it's ADDing to the file, which I don't want it to do.  Updated the code to have one > instead of >>, that solved it!